# Building gradle project with dependecy ANT project that is not integrated into gradle

Tags: maven, ant, gradle

I have a gradle project that I am working on. My project depends on another project that is not integrated into gradle. I don't not have ownership of this dependency project, therefore I am unable to integrate the project into gradle. To depend on this other project, I have uploaded a jar to a maven repository. This has been working fine since I haven't been making changes to this other project.

However, now I am making frequent changes to this dependency project and I must upload a new .jar into my maven repository every time I want to build my gradle project. (By the way, the dependency non-gradle project is built using an ANT build.xml file.) This is becoming very inefficient.

Is there a simple way to alter my build.gradle file that will run the build.xml for the other project and add the outputted .jar in as a dependency? Or does anyone have any other suggestions.

Comment: Simplest (and most correct) solution is just to automate the build/publishing of the Ant-based project.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration

Comment: have you access to the sources of that project? you could run the ant build  as part of your gradle build

Answer (score 0):

I'd just run the ant build as part of the gradle build

```
apply plugin 'java'

def antproject = 'path/to/antproject';
ant.importBuild "${antproject}/build.xml"

compile.dependsOn someTargetInAntfile
```

Then you can use jar built by ant as a dependency

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: "${antproject}/target", include: "*.jar")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would alter Lance's answer a little bit, by modyfing import of Ant build file and change names of imported targets, so that there is no collision between your Gradle's tasks and Ant targets:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
ant.importBuild('path/to/your/build.xml') { antTarget ->
  'ant-' + antTarget
}

compileJava.dependsOn "ant-jar"
```